# How many times can a power bank charge a smartphone?

Tags: lithium-ion, powerbanks

I am making a power bank with 3000mAh 18650 cells in a 3S5P configuration. This will give me 189Wh, 12.6V, and 15A. Assuming an iPhone 8 has a battery of 1821mAh or 6.96Wh, how many times it can be charged?

I found that it is `15A/1.821A` or **8.2 times** if there is no loss

Why can't it be `189Wh/6.96Wh` or **27.1 times**?

Comment: The latter is correct assuming no losses.

Comment: @Awais Saeed.  Your title doesn't match your actual question. Please change it to match your actual question.

Comment: Where do you get the current figures from ?

Comment: @RohitGupta, I was believing that the correct answer would be `189Wh/6.96Wh`. But, people on Quora were suggesting the other way around and that didn't click me. The current of any phone can be found online and current of cells from the datasheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I am creating a power bank with 3000mAh 18650 cells in a 3S5P
> configuration. This will give me 189Wh, 12.6v, and 15A.*

Three series cells implies 4.2 volts per cell (12.6 volts ÷ 3) and, that isn't sustainable. It will rapidly reduce towards maybe 3.75 volts per cell then remain somewhat stable for a decent period: -

[image]

Image from [Li-ion Voltage Analysis](https://siliconlightworks.com/li-ion-voltage).

So, more realistically you should be using 3.75 volts to calculate power. Then, you should consider that anything close to removing most of the available charge is probably going to impact the lifetime of your power bank.

Depending on how you want to work this, you might only want to remove 60% of the energy available. You should definitely read the data sheets for the cells you are using and, decide what you can realistically achieve vs cell-longevity.

Your effective useful power output might only be 15 amps x 3 x 3.75 volts x 60% for instance. Probably something around 100 Wh but, like I said it depends on the cell and other information in its data sheet. You also need to factor in the buck conversion efficiency (if one is required).

Maybe read what [The Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-501a-discharge-characteristics-of-li-ion) has to say about discharge rates and available charge for Lithium Ion power cells.

> *I found that it is (15A/1.821A) if there is no loss*

You are using 15 amps load current and 1821 mAh inappropriately. The first is figure is current and the second is current x time --> it's a meaningless figure of "something" per hour.

Comment: The SOC plot was very interesting because it was new to me. As for the last part of your explanation, I have some confusion. If a cell is of 3000mAh and 5 of them in parallel will give me a total of 15000mAh, then why 15000mAh/1821mAh is inappropriate? Both seem to be current times Time.

Comment: It's your abuse of units that's the problem. When you said 15 A you meant 15 Ah etc.. Engineering is about attention to detail.

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch the units.  You are mixing amperes (A) and ampere hours (Ah) pretty much at random.  They are not the same.

Batteries ought to be rated in watt hours (Wh.)  Manufacturers make their life simpler by using amperes hours (Ah) instead.  They do that because for a give battery chemistry, the voltage can be assumed.

When you compare batteries with different voltages, then you need to work in watt hours (Wh) to make a valid comparison.

According to [Battery University,](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/understanding-lithium-ion) the nominal voltage of a lithium ion cell (typically a lithium and cobalt cell) is 3.6V.

That means that one of your 18650 cells has a capacity of (3Ah*3.6V) = 10.8 watt hours.

A stack of three such cells has a voltage of 3.6V * 3 = 10.8V and a capacity of 3Ah*10.8V = 32.4 watt hours.

Five such stacks in parallel gives you 32.4Wh * 5 = 162 Wh.

The cell in your iPhone is a single cell.  Its voltage will be 3.6V.

You need to multiply the ampere hour rating of the battery by the nominal voltage to get watt hours.  Given the 1821 mAh rating, it has a capacity of 5.4 watt hours.

In a perfect (lossless) world, you could recharge your iPhone 162Wh/5.4Wh = 30 times.

In reality, you will have losses in converting the higher voltage of the battery bank to the lower voltage of the iPhone.  You will have losses in the discharge of the battery bank, and you will have losses in the charging of the iPhone cell.  You can tell that there are losses because all of the parts get warm - heat is lost electrical energy.

I expect you can get from maybe 15 to 20 recharges out of your battery bank.  Slow charging the iPhone (if it can do such a thing) would get more charges out of the battery bank.

Answer (score 0):

> But, why can't it be 189Wh/6.96Wh?

Who says it can't?

That is correct: 189 Wh/6.96 Wh = 27 times.

Given the inefficiencies in various DC-DC converters, it will be less than 27 times, but still in that ball park.